# How to pass data to a ng-include controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an `ng-include` html element, and want to pass some data from outside to the controller.

The main `controller` `fetches` `json` `data` from a `http webservice`, and extracts the data into the scoped variable `climadata`.

The following is `pseudocode`, but you get the idea:

```
function mainController($scope, $http) {
    $http.get().then(
        $scope.climadata = response.clima;
    );
}

<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ng-include="'clima.html'" ng-controller="climaController" onload="climamodel = climadata"></div>
</div>
```

This works fine, BUT the climadata never reaches the `climaController`. Checked as follows:

```
function climateController($scope) {
    console.log($scope.climamodel); //prints "undefinied"
};
```

The climamodel is always undefined in console, but why?

Comment: You can use service to share the data..

Comment: Isn't is possible without introducing a service for just handing the modeldata back and forth?

Comment: normaly,  you don't to do anything to get climamodel from the mainController because it's the controller parent of climateController.

Comment: angular version? this should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS : How can I pass variables between controllers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers)

Comment: Angular 1.4.3 version

Comment: @membersound, can you just check the value of $scope inside your, $http.get function. Sometimes, it takes it to be window

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is working,  the reason you getting the `undefined` is because, you get the data by `$http` request, because of that, before you get the data `climaController` will execute, at that point there is no scope variable call `climadata`.

check this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/i34Y62OSzecprnUBEEm0?p=preview)

you can see the console is printing `undefined` but you will get the data on partial `HTML` page after the data is available after ajax request.

If you want to load the `inclcude` after the ajax is complete then use `ng-if`

```
<div ng-if="climadata" ng-include="'clima.html'" ng-controller="climaController"></div>
```

if `climadata` is present then only this div process that means `include` works only if `climadata` is available.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/uMO4UwIq4sL7Aab8PPqZ?p=preview)

and you can void from `onload="climamodel = climadata"`

Comment: I think this is main of the reason  +1. But i did't test it.

Answer (score 0):

- > First you need to change `onload` to `ng-load` or `ng-init`. because `onload` can't read the angular properties.
- > You can use `$rootScope` , It is helps to pass values from a controller to another controller.

`function climateController($rootScope ) {
    console.log($rootScope.climamodel); 
};`

Also some other details, you can get here : [AngularJS: How can I pass variables between controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers)

Comment: This also gives me `undefined`.

Comment: @membersound, have you assigned `climamodel` to `rootscope` ?

Comment: No, just to normale `$scope`.

Comment: I would use a service.

Comment: @Cranio, How about directive ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function mainController($scope, $http) {
     $scope.data={};
        $http.get().then(
            $scope.data.climadata = response.clima;
        );
    }

    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <div ng-include="clima.html" ng-controller="climaController">/div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm still getting `undefined` for `console.log($scope.data.climadata)` in `climaController`.

Comment: you have to do the console.log when you the $http.get deliver it's response.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to use `$broadcast`

It is essentially a service to propogate events to child scopes(read: child controllers). The child controllers listen for the `$broadcast` event using the `$on` service.

Here's how you can implement it. In your **MainController**:

```
function mainController($scope, $http, $broadcast) { //injected broadcast
    $http.get().then(
        $scope.climadata = response.clima;
        $scope.$broadcast('climaData', $scope.climadata); //broadcast event 'climaData' and send '$scope.climadata' as argument.
    );
}
```

In your **climateController**:

```
function climateController($scope) {
    $scope.$on('climaData', function(event, args) { //listener for 'climaData' event.
        console.log(args); //args contains $scope.climadata sent from the main controller.
    }) 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i think sharing data through scope inheritance creates spaghetti code. One should inspect your code and template to understand what is going on.

For your problem i would create a service which will load and cache data. This service could be injected to both controllers.

here is sample code

```
module.factory('UserService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
var userAPI = {};
var userData = null;
var isLoading = false;

userAPI.getMyData = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(userData != null){
        deferred.resolve(userData);
    } else if(isLoading === false) {
        isLoading = true;
        $http.get('/api/data/data').then(function(resp){
            userData = resp.data;
            deferred.resolve(userData);
        }, function(err){
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;

};

return userAPI;
}]);
```