# How to call the one controller data to another controller?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, I have a 3 controllers and in 3 controllers 1 & 2 controller data call the 3 rd controller how it is? using the number of controllers it is occured

Comment: try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers

Answer (score 0):

The best way to share data between controllers is to write a service. You can find more information about services at this link to the AngularJS documentation.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services