# How to fetch scope value from one controller to another controller in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, scope

How to fetch the scope value from one controller to another controller
**html**

```
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="setLanguage('en')">English</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="setLanguage('de')">Danish</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
  .controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.setLanguage = function(language) {
        $scope.language = language;    
       }
    });
```

Comment: to get the value you have to use service

Comment: I tried To use services but its no use.... Can you try and give me the link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers refer this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service to get the value set by one controller into another controller.

```
.service('someService', function () {
  this.language = null;
})
```

Controller

```
.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, someService) {
    $scope.setLanguage = function(language) {
        $scope.language = language;
        someService.language = language;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('languageChanged');
    } 
});
```

In the other controller

```
.controller('someCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, someService) {
    $rootScope.$on('languageChanged', function () {
        $scope.language = someService.language;
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the language is getting set in the demoCtrl. Could you console.log(someService.language) in the $scope.setLanguage method after setting someService.language?

Comment: Ya i tried in demo ctrl in that its getting value name... but while giving console to servive and in another controller its getting null value

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Actually we used seperate files for header, sidebar and so on. two buttons are on navbar called "En" and "De". if we click en then lang is en and if we click de then lang should be de. so for nav bar we used notification.js and templates we used marker.js and different controller

Comment: I tried but its getting error TypeError: $rootScope.broadcast is not a function

Comment: Thanks and its working fine!. Last thing , If we click de button then language changed to de but if we refresh the page the language sets to en. This is a bug how to fix this.. If we click de then reload page it should de only

Comment: You can use cookies to persist the language selected but user

Comment: Are you using angular translate module for translations

Comment: Nope i didnt used any translation modules

Comment: Your post saved my time.Thank you so much for sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can share data between controllers with the help of either a service or you can use $emit() and $broadcast() functions.

There is a listener function in AngularJS $on() which will always be listening to the broadcast and emit events.

The syntax for the above function :

```
$scope.$emit(‘name1’,{}); //here you can send your data
$scope.$broadcast(‘name2’,{});
$scope.$on(‘name2’,function(event,args){
});
```

When using a service you can simply inject the service into your two controllers and share the data.

```
.service('someService', function () {
   var self=this;
   self.language = '';
});

.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, someService) {
    $scope.setLanguage = function(language) {
    $scope.language = language;
    someService.language = language;
    } 
});

.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope, someService) {
    $scope.language = someService.language;
 });
```

Comment: I tried but while console the service value its not getting any value.... Its giving blank value

Comment: can you create a plunkr or jsfiddle for the same

Answer (score 0):

If we want to call example method of:
`"test1 DIV controller"`
from:
`"test2 DIV controller"`
then we can write above method.

```
angular.Element(document.getelementByID('testDIV')).scope().example method name();
```

in test2DIVcontroller.

For Example :

```
<DIV ID="test1DIV" ng-controller="test1DIV controller"></DIV>
<DIV ID="test2DIV" ng-controller="test2DIV controller"></DIV>
```