# Using angularjs route how can I get a scope value into another controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have project which is a single page application.So that I am using angular js route.
In the first controller I have a $scope value.The same value i have to use in the other controller

here is my controller.js file

```
var module = angular.module("sampleApp", ['ngRoute']);

    module.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/route1', {
                    templateUrl: 'http://localhost/MyfirstApp/welcome',
                    controller: 'RouteController1'
                }).
                when('/route2', {
                    templateUrl: 'http://localhost/MyfirstApp/result',
                    controller: 'RouteController2'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        }]);

    module.controller("RouteController1", function($scope) 
    {
       $scope.value="Athira" 


    })
    module.controller("RouteController2", function($scope) {
     $scope.text=$scope.value + "Sandeep" 
    })
```

In the result page it should show as 'Athira Sandeep'

thank you for any kind of help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How can I pass variables between controllers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers)

Comment: that is using services they have explained. I want this using router

Comment: @athi not sure what you mean by saying "i want this using router"

Comment: In '$routeProvider' Can i use services or factory?. I am new in angularjs.

Comment: If we pass the controller in route provider can I get the controller scope value

Comment: @Athi you just need to refer the factory/service in the controller. It doesn't depend if you are using routing or not. The basic working of controller would remain the same. Just define a dependency on the service in the controller when you register them and use them

Comment: ok thank you.first I need to learn factory/service :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a service to share data among controllers .
Another option could be event emitters which i personally am not a fan because it populates the rootScope (in this case) with a lot of events.

What you could do it

```
angular.module('app',[])
.factory('SharedScope',function(){
var fac = this;
var scope = "";
var sharedScope = {
getScope : function(){
return fac.scope;
},
setScope: function(scope){
fac.scope = scope
}
};
return sharedScope;
})
.controller('Ctrl1',function('SharedScope'){
SharedScope.setScope("Angular");
})
.controller('Ctrl2',function('SharedScope'){
var data = SharedScope.getScope();
$scope.text = data + " is awesome"; //would get Angular is awesome
});
```

Hope this helps.