# Why model is not updating the view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to Angular JS, and I am learning it through the tutorials,

my question is why my model is not updating the view?

Following is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<div ng-controller="MyContr">
    {{xxx}}
</div>


<input type="text"  ng-model="xxx" ng-controller="MyContr" />
    <script>
    var app = angular
              .module("MyApp", [])
              .controller("MyContr", function ($scope) {
                  var xxx="Alexander"
                  $scope.xxx = xxx;
                 });
</script>
```

Comment: you should only have one copy of `ng-controller` on the page.

Comment: Thanks, bud, it helped, should I go for Angular JS 1 or Angular JS 2, because I heard that Angular JS 2 is completely different than angular JS 1 ?

Comment: angular2 is a complete redesign, it has nothing at all in common with angularjs.

Comment: Any message in console? maybe error?

Comment: So, keeping the future perspective in mind, what you recommend me to go for?

Comment: you aren't going to get recommendations from questions or comments here....

Answer (score 1):

According to the code shown on the question, It seems that your are calling `MyContr` twice,

one here:

```
<div ng-controller="MyContr">
    {{xxx}} <!-- xxx (instance 1) -->
</div>
```

and another here:

```
<!-- xxx (instance 2) --> 
<input type="text"  ng-model="xxx" ng-controller="MyContr" />
```

... so two (different) instances of the same controller are being created. This way each instance have two different `xxx` var, each one has its own `xxx` variable on its scope.

**Solution**

*Option 1* - You can share the data between instances (see [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers) and [AngularJS: How can I pass variables between controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers))

Option 2 - Enclose both html elements inside the same instance of the `MyContr` like this:

```
<span ng-controller="MyContr">
    <div>
        {{xxx}}
    </div>
    <input type="text"  ng-model="xxx" />
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution.  I've been working on a similar problem on and off for weeks.  In my case, I didn't have multiple ng-controller tags, but had one in first div and other divs didn't recognize it.  Enclosed all divs in a parent div and moved ng tags there, and it worked.