# Unknown provider: dataProvider

Tags: angularjs

Im using the following code and the 'firebaseDetailCtrl' is throwing an error on page:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataProvider <- data <-
>   firebaseDetailCtrl

I'm not an expert, I know there are other explainations of this, but i cant find a logical solution and some help.

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase', 'ngRoute']);

myApp.controller("todoCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref();

  // download the data into a local object
  $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
});

myApp.controller('firebaseDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'data',
  function($scope, $routeParams, data) {
    $scope.url = $routeParams.id; 

    $scope.todoWork2 = data.query();
  }]);


myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/projects/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/firebase-details.html',
      controller: 'firebaseDetailCtrl'
    }).
    when('/projects', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/firebase-items.html',
    controller: 'todoCtrl'
  }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/projects'
      });
  }]);
```

Comment: `data` in the `firebaseDetailCtrl` controller is not defined here. Be sure where it is defined in your app.

Comment: thanks for the initial answer, can you be more specific on how to pass data into to the controller.

Comment: have you gone through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers?

Comment: aha, very useful post. I will digest it now. Thanks for taking the time to reply, cheers.