# How can I access a variable data which is in a different js file using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to use a variable data in another js file. How do I do that in anularjs.

In one.js file i have a variable tagText="SAP" and I want to use its value in another js file(two.js). How do I do that in angularjs?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: so access a variable inside one controller from another controller? show the relevant code please.

Comment: access value from one controller to a directive. I have a variable $scope.tagText in the controller (searchController.js) and I want to read this value in my directive(autoComplete.js).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How can I pass variables between controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

As of my point of view 
you can create a service of that file oneService.js

```
myApp.service('oneService', oneService);

function oneService(){
    var tagText;
    return {
        getTagText:getTagText,
        setTagText:setTagText
    };
    function getTagText(){
        return tagText;
    }
    function setTagText(tagText){
        this.tagText=tagText;
    }
}
```

> Inject this service in any controller and you can access tagText variable on that controller via getter & setter

Service in Singleton in angular, at a time you have latest value of variable